# Grease pencil overlapping everything

Tags: eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil

I'm new to blender and I am trying to block out some compositions, but is there a way I can get it so that my grease pencil strokes don't overlap everything I try to put over it? In this case im dealing with an image plane, using blender 2.8, and rendering with eevee.[image]